# From local to gloabl comparison of Riemannian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a beginner question in Riemannian geometry. Given a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$, I assume this metric is represented locally by a family of positive definite matrices $(A_q)_q$ in local coordinates.

I assume I have an inequality of the type : $A_q \geq M^{-1}_q$ near every $q \in \mathcal{M}$, where $M_q$ is a positive definite matrix and the inequality is in the sense of Loewner order.

Is there anything intelligent to say about the $g$-geodesic distance ?
For example, a link between the $g$-geodesic distance and the $M$-geodesic distance or an integral linked with $M$ ?

My general question is whether it is possible to turn a local comparison of a metric/cometric (that appears in the Hamiltonian equations of geodesics) into a global result on the geodesic distance ?

EDIT : I forgot the inverse on $M_q$.

Comment: What is the Loewner order?

Comment: I mean that $A \geq B$ iff $A - B$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: Ah, OK, the "obvious" order. So the $g$-length of any curve is $\ge$ the $M$-length of the curve. Doesn't this establish what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ted. Sorry I made a typo : I forgot an inverse. In fact, there is this metric/cometric comparison that in not really clear in my head. I edited my original message.

Comment: Now it’s highly dubious. Except in rare cases and with gross bounds, we cannot relate $M$-length and $M^{-1}$-length.

Comment: You should note that the matrices $A$ and $M$ depend on the coordinates. Each parameterized family of matrices defines a Riemannian metric. So you're comparing two different RIemannian metric. My main advice is to keep studying Riemannian geometry from a good textbook (there are many by now. The most popular relatively new ones are by John Lee, Loring Tu, and Peter Petersen. Make sure that as you go along, you develop a solid understanding of manifolds.

Comment: Your inequality does not really make sense since it is coordinate-dependent. Try to formulate your question in coordinate-independent manner and see if you can come up with something reasonable.